# Python. Получение имени списка

Tags: python, list

К примеру, есть список `xlist = ["Test",1,2,3]`. Как можно получить имя этого списка (`xlist`)?

Comment: А зачем вам это? Может быть у исходной задачи есть более подходящее решение? В текущем виде можно, например, посмотреть на `locals()` и найти там ваш список

Comment: @ВОРОН мне просто надо имя переменной, чтобы после её записать.

Я пробовал записывать простые переменные через лямбду: `var_name = lambda x:[ n for n in globals() if id(globals()[n]) == id(x) ][0]`, но тут не прошло.

Comment: Ваше решение выглядит несколько чужеродно для Python. Попробуйте описать Вашу *задачу* (не решение). Также, пожалуйста, укажите входные данные, по которым Вы планируете идентифицировать переменную.

Comment: @soon ,нашёл решение: http://pastebin.com/Xay6d02N

Comment: В таком случае, Вы можете оформить его как ответ на ru.SO

Comment: похожий вопрос: [How can you print a variable name in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/592746/4279)

Answer (score 5):

Имя переменной можно получить, например, следующим образом:

```
var1 = []

for name, value in list(locals().items()):
    if var1 is value:
        print(name)
```

Но есть и подводные камни, связанные с оптимизацией:

```
var1 = "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away…"
var2 = "A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away…"

for name, value in list(locals().items()):
    if var1 is value:
        print(name)
```

Вывод программы:

```
var2
var1
```

То есть одному объекту в памяти может соответствовать более одного имени.

С использованием модуля `inspect` можно оформить это в виде функции:

```
import inspect

def get_variable_name(var):
    return [name for name, value in inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items() if value is var]
```

Comment: `locals()` — это локальное пространство имён, оно не включает имена из охватывающих областей. Даже без всякой оптимизации, объект может иметь разное кол-во имён, например, если объект принадлежит какому-нибудь контейнеру, типа списка в Питоне, то у него может вообще не быть обычного имени, например, `L[0] = L[1] = []`: в данном случае пустой список (`[]`) доступен как `L[0]`, так и `L[1]`, но у него нет простого имени (идентификатора) вроде `xyz`. `inspect.currentframe()` может не работать на других реализациях Питона.